# GitLab delete incompletely imported Project

Tags: git, gitlab

I attempted to create a GitLab repository via `Repo by URL`. That operation never produced a result and now I have a project without a project page (404 Error when trying to open it).
The problem is, the name still appears in the listing of projects and I would like to reuse that project name.

Is there any way to delete this project?

Answer (score 0):

You could go to settings -> general -> advanced (click on expand) and then scroll to the last to delete the project

p.s assuming you have the right privileges for the project/repository